How the the G₂ extension curve was computed for EIP‒197?
The G1 curve is simply the normal altbn128 which means Y2=X3+3 having order q=21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495617
But the specification create an other curve in an extension field, having the same q. In order to have that same q order, the parameters are Y2=X3+3÷(i+9) over F_p2 = F_p[i] ÷ (i^2 + 1) instead of the prime field.
Now the question : how such parameters got computed ?

An interesting question! Unfortunately, I doubt you can find an answer here. I wonder if the EIP is inspired by some other work - maybe try to find a community that knows about the background...

@LauriPeltonen Unfortunately, most cryptographers want to promote not for proft involvment and thus not crypto.

@user2284570 AFAIK the curve was created by Zcash project. This link have more details about the parameters computation https://hackmd.io/@jpw/bn254.

@Ismael so I need to know where such Baretto Naehrig rules come from.

In the same link they point to the original paper for the BN curves "Pairing-Friendly Elliptic Curves of Prime Order (PDF)". Sorry, but my math is not enough to understand that paper. Probably if you look for bn254 you might find more details.

@Ismael in b254, they just apply the Barretto Naehrig rules to a specific prime modulus.
